# Generated systemd unit does not start on boot

Tags: systemd

I have a generator script (as described by `man systemd.generator`) in `/etc/systemd/system-generators/` directory.

The generator runs on boot and successfully generates a unit file into dir `/run/systemd/generator.late/` (using the `ARGV[3]` argument). The generator also adds symlink to `/run/systemd/generator.late/multi-user.target.wants/` as I want to start the service on boot (specifically when network is up).

The unit file and the symlink are generated successfully. The problem is that the service is not started automatically.

When I issue command `service myService status`, it says inactive and the log is empty which makes me believe that it did not even **try** to start the service. If I do `service myService start`, it starts (= the unit file is okay).

In an attempt to find solution to this problem, I have copied this generated unit file to `/etc/systemd/system` and manually added symlink to `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` and rebooted the machine. The service DID start at boot.

This all makes me think that the link from `/run/systemd/generator.late/multi-user.target.wants/` to my unit is not enough to start the **generated** service. I have inspected other unit files generated by system in `/run/systemd/generator.late/` and they seem to do the exactly same thing and are using the symlink as I do. So what is going on in here?

Is there a way to troubleshoot this? Is the symlink I am creating wrong? Do I need to do something more than just the symlink?

The final generator script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

serviceName=myService
bin=/path/to/my/executable
generatorDir=$3
unitFile=$generatorDir/$serviceName.service

cat > "$unitFile" <<EOF
[Unit]
Description=$serviceName service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=$bin

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

mkdir "$generatorDir/multi-user.target.wants" 2>/dev/null
ln -s "$unitFile" "$generatorDir/multi-user.target.wants/$serviceName.service"
```

Note: the real script is little bit more complicated, this is just a minimalistic example.

I am using Ubuntu 16.10.
I will provide additional info if needed.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? Maybe comment on the answer, and if successful, accept the answer as such.

Comment: One problem *may* be that the generated symlink is pointing at a transient file that no longer exists after the generator runs.  I still have not been able to get this to work, though, so I'm not sure that's an issue.

Comment: @rich Unfortunately I never got it to work. I had assumed it was a bug in the systemd that was in Ubuntu 16. Four years later and nothing changed? I am not surprised ;-)

Comment: I just tested with [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NzqFTYfRPs/) and the service is active after boot. I'm using systemd [248.3](https://github.com/systemd/systemd-stable/releases/tag/v248.3) on Arch Linux though.

Answer (score 2):

The way to troubleshoot this is to boot your system, and when your service does not start as expected, you can run the command:

> systemd-analyze dump

This outputs a very detailed list of information about each unit, including the dependencies.  From this you can usually figure out why your unit did not go into active state.

Comment: Without more context, I am unable to find anything relevant in the dump.  The generators show timestamps for running, but the relevant generator does not appear anywhere in the dump.  The files appear in the /run/systemd/generator dir, so I know it's basically working, but nothing gets started.